# Add and divide 2 rows to get percentage in SQL

Tags: sql

From the data in the first table how do I get a simple percentage of total calculation:

[image]

```
two / (two + three) = 2 / (2 + 3) = 0.4
```

to arrive at:

[image]

Comment: what about one?

Comment: ignore one, just need two and three

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below -

```
select ((case when name='two' then value end)*1.0)/sum(value)
from t
where name in ('two','three')
```

Answer (score 2):

You would rarely do something like this in SQL. Anyway, you can do:

```
with
two as (select value from t where name = 'two'),
three as (select value from t where name = 'three')
select 1.0 * two.value / (two.value + three.value) as answer
from two
cross join three
```

Result:

```
 answer                 
 ---------------------- 
 0.40000000000000000000
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hLdF4RNUDg4MkZcLCJGBq2/0).